# What does "Sandbagging" (or sometimes sandboxing) mean as an expression in startup or sales and where is it coming from?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, etymology

I have heard one meaning of it in the context of a personal goal is to set a too-easy goal (i.e., that you know you can easily achieve). I also heard it is coming from golf. Can someone shed more light on this?

To be clear, I was not referring to computer science or computing area where it means to separate a piece of software on a computer system so it can only use particular programs, files, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Is probably refers to the idea of a sand box as a sand pit for children to play.

Comment: Please indicate your research. Have you tried a dictionary? It should be possible to work it out from the [various meanings of sandbox as a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sandbox): it means using as a sandbox, doing in a sandbox, or putting in a sandbox.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sandbox) lists the verb's sense in computing: <<
 
_sandbox_
verb [transitive]   [computing]  [specialized]

to separate a piece of software on a computer system so it can only use particular programs, files, etc: 
• _Each application is sandboxed into its own memory space so that it does not bring others down if it crashes._ 
•  _The new feature is said to sandbox potentially untrusted graphical applications_ >> By extension, _[doing a test run] in an environment that will not endanger others_ (cf _quarantine_).

Comment: Do you think you can define the term in the question and focus on asking about the origin of the phrase? I think it might be pretty easy to find a definition on the internet.

Comment: Well, FWIW, I first searched for sandboxing and I didn't find anything. When I searched with sandbagging, there were relevant pages. I'm not sure the two words could be used interchangeably though.

Comment: Two completely different ideas here. Sandbagging is cheating. It comes from (illegal) practice of carrying moveable sandbag ballast on racing sailboats. Then they made a racing rule that allowed sandbagging, and there promptly developed a very distinct class of boats around this rule based on the sharpies of New England. But the idiom still refers to the cheating aspect of sandbagging. It can also mean duping an opponent into a competition in which they have scant chance of winning.

Comment: In chess, if you lose on purpose in a bunch of inconsequential tournaments to lower your rating, you can then clean house in one or two money games each year. This is sandbagging.

Comment: Sandboxing is unrelated. When you put kids in a sandbox, they can play at will and not get hurt; and they tend to stay put where you can watch them. That's the whole idea of the sandbox. In tech speak, a sandbox is a safe space where you can explore how things work without disrupting the real world when you goof up.

Comment: This is a Latex sandbox - http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/akay/teaching/latex/

Comment: Thank you @phil for explaining the origin of each! these were quite interesting to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Sandbagging in sales is the act of pushing deals from one commission period to another. This might be monthly or quarterly.

Comission being the money paid out as a reward for closing that deal, typically a percentage.

This is done for numerous reasons but typically if you are overachieving in one period, you want to get a headstart in the next.

Salespeople have targets they must hit and are frowned upon if they dont.

For example, my target is 5 deals in Q1. I have closed 5 and can close 2 more before the end of the quarter, but instead of squaring them away I push the final contract signing to Q2 and those deals now count towards Q2. 100% of target for Q1 and 40% for Q2 before the quarter has started.

Sometimes it may be done as commission payouts are changing or even to punish managers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer helpful about sandbagging. According to comments by Phil Sweet in the question, Sandboxing is a completely different concept though.

“Sandbagging” term originates from the late 1880s and relates to somebody who sneaks up on another person from behind and beats them with a sandbag. It was a dishonest move back in the days. Today, the term also implies some kind of trickery but not that dangerous.

Basically, it’s the idea of “under-promise and over-deliver.” And unlike in the 1880s, sandbagging can be a beneficial thing today. You’re packing your sandbags with deals and may suddenly surprise your management or investors with better results than they are anticipating at the end of the month.

[Examples of similar context](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/management/sandbagging/)

[Original regerence link](https://snov.io/glossary/sandbagging/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).